# Centroid of a javafx Shape

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

How can one find the centroid of a javafx `Shape` object?

**Longer story**: I am highlighting the intersections of 2 or more shapes, and need to position text over this intersection - ideally centering the text at the centroid. Given the potential for these intersections to be irregular, using the center of the intersection's layout bounds for calculations quite often result in mis-positioning of the text. For example, constructing the code below results in the center point that is offset relative to the conceptual center:

```
public class Test extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        /*
         * Create shapes
         */
        Circle s1 = new Circle(100, 100, 75);
        s1.setFill(new Color(1, 0, 0, 0.25));
        Circle s2 = new Circle(200, 100, 75);
        s2.setFill(new Color(0, 1, 0, 0.25));
        Circle s3 = new Circle(150, 125, 50); 
        s3.setFill(new Color(0, 0, 1, 0.25));
        /*
         * Create the intersection
         */
        Shape intersection = Shape.intersect(s3, s2);
        intersection = Shape.subtract(intersection, s1);
        intersection.setStroke(Color.RED);

        /*
         * Create a point that shows the layout bounds center
         */
        Circle boundsCenter = new Circle();
        boundsCenter.setRadius(2d);
        boundsCenter.setCenterX(intersection.getLayoutBounds().getMinX() + intersection.getLayoutBounds().getWidth()/2);
        boundsCenter.setCenterY(intersection.getLayoutBounds().getMinY() + intersection.getLayoutBounds().getHeight()/2);
        boundsCenter.setFill(Color.RED);
        intersection.setFill(null);


        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(s1, s2, s3, intersection, boundsCenter);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    } 
}
```

I would prefer to rely on the javafx API to do so (java 8 compatible), if at all possible.

**One Option** I have considered is to estimate the centroid by sampling using the Shape API and calculating the centroid of Points that fall within the given `Shape`:

```
//estimate the centroid by random sampling 
int maxEstimate = 100;
double x = 0; double y = 0; double count = 0;
while(count < maxEstimate) {
    double randomX = intersection.getLayoutBounds().getMinX() + Math.random() * intersection.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
    double randomY = intersection.getLayoutBounds().getMinY() + Math.random() * intersection.getLayoutBounds().getHeight();
    Circle test = new Circle(randomX, randomY, 1d);
    Shape isInside = Shape.intersect(c, intersection);
    if ( isInside.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() > 0 || isInside.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() > 0 ) {
        x += randomX;
        y += randomY;
        count++;
    }
}
double centroidX = x / count;
double centroidY = y / count;
```

The problem with this method is that it is non-deterministic, can be inaccurate for smaller number of iterations, and quite intensive and time consuming for a larger number of shapes (and/or a more accurate measurement)

Comment: Will the shapes always be convex?  It makes the calculation a bit easier if they are.  And if the shapes are constructed by intersecting a number of circles, then they always will be convex.

Comment: Currently, they should always be intersections of 2 or more circles (so based upon your comment always be convex?)

Comment: So you could iterate over the X values, picking out the highest and lowest Y co-ordinates.  You can get an average Y co-ordinate by accumulating these and applying a weighting based on the difference.  And you can get an average X co-ordinate by just using the weighting.  I might have time later to write some actual code.

Comment: Actually, now that I look at your code more closely, I see that you've used `subtract` as well as `intersect`, which unfortunately does not preserve convexity.  My algorithm will have to be much more complicated.

Comment: I would like to see that code that allows you to center the text once you have the centroid values calculated. You may already have this figured out. If not, it's something to think about.

Comment: Without the constraint that the shapes have to be convex, I can't think of a good way of doing this.  The algorithm I was considering is no better than checking every pixel individually for being within the shape.